# Grails loading select box from database makes it multi-selectable

Tags: grails

I am trying to make a custom edit page. I grab the object ID and make an instance of the object. But when I try to specify a value for the select box, the box renders as multi-selectable. I need it to default to the selection based on the child, but only be single select. I have tried multiple="false" but my program is just ignoring it.

My object is a sample that contains parameters (children) that are associated with each sample. I have an algorithm that grabs each parameter and builds lists of each unique name, value and information. Some samples only have parameters with a value and no information, so they go into one map, while samples that have a value and information go into another map.

here is the algorithm and my action:

```
def updateSample = {

    def sid =   params.sample.id // get the id of the sample object
    def sampleInstance = Sample.get(sid)// creates instance
    def children = sampleInstance?.sampleParameters


    /* ------ gets a list of unique parameter names ------*/
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<SampleParameter>> oldMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<SampleParameter>>(); // for single parameter options
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<SampleParameter>>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, ArrayList<SampleParameter>>>(); // for multiple parameter options
    for (def result : SampleType.get(sampleInstance.sampleType.id).sampleParameters.sort {it.value}) { // only iterate over assigned sample paramters
        if (result.information != null) { // we are working with 3 parameters 
            if (!map.containsKey(result.name)) { // if map does not already contain the key
                map.put(result.name, new HashMap<String, ArrayList<SampleParameter>>()); //add the name and a map to hold the values from the table's information column
            }
            if (!map.get(result.name).containsKey(result.value)) {
                map.get(result.name).put(result.value, new ArrayList<SampleParameter>());
            }
            map.get(result.name).get(result.value).add(result);
        } else {// otherwise we are only working with two parameters
            if (!oldMap.containsKey(result.name)) { // if the name does not already exist in oldMap, add it
                oldMap.put(result.name, new ArrayList<SampleParameter>()); // holds values
            }
            oldMap.get(result.name).add(result); //adds value to the list
        }
    } 

    /* invokes template and passes a map to be rendered inside of  <div id="parameter"> in sample.gsp */
    render(template:'updatesample' , model:[sid:sid,sampleInstance:sampleInstance,children:children,
            oldMap:oldMap, map:map])



}
```

The lists build just fine if I don't specify a value. But when i specify a value, the correct value is highlighted but the box is multiselectable.

Here is my template code that gets rendered on the gsp;

```
 <g:each in="${oldMap?.sort()}"> 
    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="top"><b>${it.getKey()}:</b></td> 
      <td><g:select optionKey="id" optionValue="value" name="sampleParameters" id="parameter" value="${sampleInstance?.sampleParameters}" from='${it.getValue()}' /></td>
    </tr>
  </g:each>
  <g:each var="valueMap" in="${map?.sort()}"> 
    <tr><td align="right" valign="top"><b>${valueMap.getKey()}:</b></td></tr>
      <g:each var="infoMap" in="${valueMap?.getValue()?.sort()}">
        <tr>
          <td align="right" valign="top">${infoMap.getKey()}:</td>
          <td><g:select multiple ="false" noSelection="${['':'Select One...']}"optionKey="id" optionValue="information" name="sampleParameters" id="parameter" value="${sampleInstance?.sampleParameters}" from="${infoMap?.getValue()?.sort(){it.information}}" /></td>
        </tr>
      </g:each>
  </g:each>
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove "multiply" in tag at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sampleInstance?.sampleParameters` returns a `Collection` object and so, if Grails detects a `Collection` in the `value` attribute and the `multiple` attribute hasn't been set, it will set the `multiple` attribute for you.  Thus rendering your select as a multi-select.

Setting `multiple="false"` won't help as Grails just allows the attribute to pass straight through so you get a `<select multiple="false" ...>` tag and just the presence of the attribute may cause the browser to render it as a multi-select.

Try passing in only a single instance from `sampleParameters` as the `value` attribute to have a single select field.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me to figure out this issue. I had to iterate over the collection and then it works as intended.